# How should my objects be structured for proper MVVM in Knockout?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm working with knockout and am trying to stay true the MVVM structure and trying to make the objects have that dependency on each other.

Here is what I currently have, be gentle, I'm still learning this:

Model, ViewModel, Service definitions:

```
var App = window.App || {};

(function(ns, $, ko) {
    ns.Models = {};
    ns.ViewModels = {};
    ns.Services = ns.Services || {};

    //Service def
    ns.Services.SearchService = function() {
        this.SearchByName = function(name, callback) {
            $.get("/api/SearchByName/" + name, function(d){
                callback(d);
            });
        };
    };

    //Model Def
    ns.Models.SearchResultModel = function(json) {
        var self = this;

        ko.mapping.fromJS(json, {}, self);
    };

    //ViewModel def
    ns.ViewModels.SearchResultsViewModel = function() {
        var self = this;

        self.dataService = new ns.Services.SearchService();
        self.SearchResults = ko.observableArray();

        self.GetSearchResultsByName = function(name){
            self.dataService.SearchByName(name, function(d) {
                $.each(d, function(i, e) { self.SearchResults.push(new ns.Models.SearchResultModel(e)); });
            });
        };
    };
}(App, jQuery, ko));
```

And I can currently use it like so:

```
var vm = new App.ViewModels.SearchResultsViewModel();

vm.GetSearchResultsByName("Doe");

ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("search-results-form"));
```

This is just my starting point and it seems like the `ko.applyBindings(...)` should be in the ViewModel somewhere.

With all that, am I going the right direction for this or am I completely off with it?

Comment: You may be interested in [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing unusual looking. It's a hard question to answer because if there *isn't* something you're doing wrong, there's not much to say...

One thing I noticed was that

```
$.get("/api/SearchByName/" + name, function(d){
    callback(d);
});
```

should by replaced with

```
$.get("/api/SearchByName/" + escape(name)).done(callback);
```

The `name` should be escaped because it might contain invalid URL characters, and there's no reason to wrap the callback. (In general, the expression `function (x) { f(x) }` is just adding unnecessary indirection to the simpler expression `f`.)

In the `GetSearchResultsByName` function, a name more descriptive than `d` would be good, especially since you're being so verbose with your naming elsewhere.

Comment: a small improvement again would be to do `$.get("/api/SearchByName/" + escape(name)).done(callback)`